# How to setup a stand alone Web application testing environment?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web, web-applications

I am pretty new to web application development and testing,currently working on a project which requires me to set up a stand alone environment for testing the Web application. The idea is web application should be testable and the server should be in simulated mode.

As, i was researching came to know that one of the ways it can be done is by node.js which can help in server application for the web app and data can be sent to Web application by JSON.

Please let me know if there is a better way to test standalone web application. All possible ideas are welcome.Please suggest.

Comment: What is the production server built in?
What type of database is being used, if any?

Answer (score 1):

It should pretty same as how you setup your production server but test server should have its own database instance and should collide with production data.I didn't get the point about using nodejs. ?? Your tech stack should be same as the production tech stack. Then only it will be called simulated environment.